# Is there a way to make the battery level easier to see on some Android phones such as Xiaomi?

Tags: battery, xiaomi, miui

I looked at the battery level on Samsung A32 and it was easy to look at, but on Xiaomi it looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to make it easier to look at?  Right now I have to go to Settings -> Battery to get a better idea.  We might be able to change the theme to make it easier to look at, but it'd be a overkill to change the theme for the whole phone just for the battery level.

For example, down below the status line, it says

```
4:41                             Clear 21°C
Friday May 28
```

in big fonts.  Is it possible to add the battery level display there?

Comment: Battery, time and such elements in the status bar are decided by system UI properties and can't be changed on isolation. Two options I know of - one is rooted means to change the appearance, second is battery monitoring apps that add their own icon which may be more legible but you still end up displaying the system battery, which can be quite ugly. Rooting is the preferred option if nothing offered by OS is preferred option

Comment: What is for you "easier to see"? For myself I prefer the batter percent value or are you referring to the battery color (white on light blue background)? In the latter case have you tried to change the background image to one that has a dark area in the upper part?

Comment: I can't really tell if it is 36% vs 96% or 26%... the percentage background is not that apparent